# Adding MD5 to a UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, md5

Sorry if this is a silly question but having difficulty in getting this working!!

I have searched hi and low and it seems the code below will generate an md5 hash but im not sure how to get my 2 password textfields to use it to generate to send to the server. Please advise I would be greatful thankful.

Mike

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

- (NSString *)stringWithMD5Hash:(NSString *)inStr {
const char *cStr = [inStr UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
    result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
    result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15] ];
```

}

Comment: Hi guys, so im nearly there i have this now it's printing out an NSLOG from the input into the password field 1 but just wont send it to the server is this a code issue or server? NSString *str = self.newPassword1.text;
    
    NSString *md5 = [str md5];
    
    NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", str, md5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this code into a `Category` (see the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html)) which adds it to the NSString class. You can add it either as a class

```
+ (NSString *)stringWithMD5Hash:(NSString *)inStr {
  const char *cStr = [inStr UTF8String];
  unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
      result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
      result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15] ];
}
```

or as an instance method

```
- (NSString *)MD5Hash {
  const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
  unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
  CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
      result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
      result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15] ];
}
```

Then you can call it just as `sudo rm -rf` said:

```
NSString *md5 = [NSString stringWithMD5Hash:textField.text];
```

or

```
NSString *md5 = [textField.text MD5Hash];
```

Comment: Actually, if you're adding it as a category wouldn't it be:  `NSString *md5 = [NSString stringWithMD5Hash:textField.text];`

Answer (score 3):

Call `[self stringWithMD5Hash:yourTextField.text]`. You might want to lowerCase the return of the function as most server side languages generate MD5 hashes with lowercase characters.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy Assuming the method is in the same class as your textfield, just do this:

```
NSString *md5 = [self stringWithMD5Hash:textField.text];
```